# basic css addressing class inside div class

Tags: css

I've got basic css problem.

I want to add `display: none; property` to `input-group_details` element in my `div class="textAdd"`.

divs from the console:

```
<div class="textAdd input-group input-group--text-field input-group--single-line 
            input-group--multi-line input-group--full-width primary--text">
   <label>Dodaj własne</label>
   <div class="input-group__input">
      <textarea tabindex="0" aria-label="Dodaj własne" rows="5"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group__details">
     <!---->
   </div>
</div>
```

When I write sth like:

```
 .input-group__details{
    display: none;
  }
```

It works, but I want address only the element in my textAdd class. I cannot simply add new class to my `<div class="input-group__details">` because it's actively rendered by the framework.

Comment: this is such a CSS basic that i couldn't even find a duplicate.. here it is: `.textAdd .input-group__details{ display: none; }`..

Comment: sorry to tell you really bad coding.. ""--" "__" lot of classes for single element  not the write way to write html/css code

Comment: @Overflowrun this is Vuetify vuejs css framework ;)

Comment: @Overflowrun But it does the job done ;) anyway - how to address the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are expecting

```css
.textAdd .input-group__details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="textAdd input-group input-group--text-field input-group--single-line 
            input-group--multi-line input-group--full-width primary--text">
   <label>Dodaj własne</label>
   <div class="input-group__input">
      <textarea tabindex="0" aria-label="Dodaj własne" rows="5"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group__details">
     This is hidden .... Some text here
   </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group__details">
 This is not hidden ... Some text here
</div>
```

Comment: you are right - it works! I wrote `.textAdd.input-group__details` without space between elements and it didn't work

Comment: @gileneusz without the space it would try to select elements that have both classes. I suggest you read some CSS selector tutorial ;)

Comment: @Kaddath no time for this. I'm learning crash course by doing ;) but thanks for a valuable advice!